# Read Text file and Email in Plain Text without affecting the original Text

Tags: c#

I have a plain text file that I need to read in using C#, manipulate it a bit then I need to email it. That's easy enough, but it also has to stay in the same format as it's original state:

This is an excerpt from a sample file "mySample.txt":

```
   *****************************NB!!!!**********************************
   *Please view http://www.sdfsdf.comsdfsdfsdf  .                      *
   *********************************************************************


        *** DO NOT DELETE or ALTER ANY OF THE FOLLOWING TEXT ***

                          Company X PTY.
                    Lorem Ipsum Office
                  Last Change - 01 February 2008

           APPLICATION TO ESTABLISH A COMMUNITY WITHIN
                THE RESTIN DISTRICT OF THE IPSUM.

    ===================================================================

    1. COMMUNITY and ACTION

    Give the name of the community.  This is the name that will be
    used in tables and lists associating the community with the name
    district and community forum.  The community names that are
    delegated by Lorem are at the district level
    The Action field specifies whether this is a 'N'ew application, an
    'U'pdate or a 'R' removal.

    1a. Complete community name:**{0}**
    1b. Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [R]emoval :**{1}**
```

As you can see I've got place holders {0} and {1} in the file which is to be replaced by an automated process.

In my C# I'm using a stream reader to read the entire file into a StringBuilder object then replacing the place holders using the StringBuilder.AppendFormat method.

The problem is when I add the text to a email message body and send it the format ends up looking different. It looks like a bunch of spaces or tabs get removed in the process.

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create mail client
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubmitToEmail"]);
        message.Bcc.Add("xyz@test.com");
        message.Subject = "Test Subject";

        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;
        message.Body = _PopulateForm(_GatherInput());//calls method to read the file and replace values
        client.Send(message);

        //cleanup
        client = null;
        message.Dispose();
        message = null;

    }
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to keep the formatting in tact?

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Plaintext email doesn't support tabs.  If your original file contains tabs, expand them to spaces.  There's a command to do this in the Visual Studio editor.

Comment: Can you me more specific than "it looks different"?  If you open it up in a hex editor, exactly which bytes are missing?

Comment: @arx The command is Edit -> Advanced -> Untabify selected line. It has to be done on the original Text File.

Comment: Hi @arx, the text file uses only spaces. I double checked using your method and there's definitely no tabs

Comment: I got a response from the automated server, but it's an error: Can not decode base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to have been with .net and the Mail message object. Instead of adding the content to the Body property, you have to create an alternateView object and add it to that. That solved my problem.

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that you're sending plain text as HTML. It's natural that the layout gets changed because HTML is displayed differently than text. Plain text has new lines (`\n`), tabs (`\t`), etc., while HTML has line breaks (`<BR>`) and different layout methods.

If I were you, I would 1st start out by replacing new lines with `<BR>` (there should be a replace function `x.Replace("\n", "<BR>");`)

As for the text items that are centered, wrap them in `<p style="text-align:center" }>`, `</p>`.

Comment: Hi mj, my text file is plain text, which i'm reading into a stringbuilder object. And the message body is set to Ascii and IsBodyHtml is set to false. There's no HTML involved?

Comment: What browser/email client are you using to view the message in? If it's outlook or something like that, there's an option to have it display in plain text.

Comment: It's outlook but definitely in plain text only.

Comment: Is it possible for you to save the email off, view it in notepad and see if the characters (\n, \t) are still there?

Comment: hi mj_ I've added myself as a recipient for the automated email and after receiving it I saved the file as a plain text file. When I opened it, it's perfectly formatted. I'm at a bit of a loss right now

Comment: I'm getting an error back from the automated server now, which is at least a step forward... Can not decode base64

Comment: Your comment that says you opened it and it's perfectly fine points to a email client issue. What did you do to get the base64 error?